# How to delete a string of text before a Bookmark if a condition is met?

Tags: vba, ms-word

First and foremost, I'm a novice at this.

The situation is as follows:
A Word template is being edited by a VBA macro upon generating a document. I need to improve the VBA macro by deleting a set string of text (A) and replacing it with a different string of text (B) upon the condition that another specific string of text (C) can be found in the document.

There's a Boolean function

```
Function findrange(tekst As String) As Boolean
    Set place = Documents(ActiveDocument.Name).Content
    If place.Find.Execute(findtext:=tekst) = True Then
        findrange = True
    Else
        findrange = False
    End If
End Function
```

By which I can identify if that string of text (A) is found in the document. So far so good.

What I need is to delete that string of text (A), if it is found in the document, upon the condition that another string of text (C) can be found in the document.

How do I go about it? I've tried

```
If findrange("C") = True Then
    If findrange("A") = True Then place.Text = ""
```

But If True Then doesn't allow nesting Ifs apparently.

Comment: Nested `If` statements are certainly allowed. It isn't possible to see from the code that you have posted what the scope of the variable `place` is. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66138357/edit) to show the full context of your code.

Comment: What does this have to do with bookmarks? Your thread title refers to them but nothing in the body of your post does.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up two Range variables.

```
Dim rngA as Word.Range
Dim rngC as Word.Range
```

Then upon finding the Text(A) using your findRange function you need to store the found range in the rngA variable.

```
Set rngA = place.Range
```

Next, run the findRange function again using Text(C), and assuming it is found you can then replace the rngA.text with your Text(B) data.

Comment: Unfortunately `Set rngA = place.Range` will fail. It can be determined from the code in the question that `place` ***is*** a range. It may also fail if `place` is only valid within the scope of the `findrange` function (there isn't enough information to tell if the issue is the scope or simply a missing `End If`)

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim RngA As Range, RngB As Range
With ActiveDocument
  Set RngA = .Range: Set RngB = .Range
  With RngA.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "String C"
    .Execute
    If .Found = True Then
      With RngB.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "String A"
        .Replacement.Text = "String B"
        .Format = False
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      End With
    End If
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```